# To prevent click  datagridview mistakenly

Tags: .net, winforms, exception, data-binding, datagridview

I have a datagridview in which I want to copy some rows to a collection by a button event.
Here arises two questions.

1. If I click outside the grid, it shouldn't fire it because it will throw an exception.
   How to prevent it?
2. Th second one seems to be simple? It is an empty datarow, then it should be prohibtted as well.

   ```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           if (// need condition here.)
           {
               DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
               DataRow row = currentDataRowView.Row;
               DataRowlist.Add(row);
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
    }
   ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check if there is a currentrow:

if (DataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
{
...
}